# 'PFObject' does not have a member named 'subscript'

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, swift

I understand, this particular error was already posted here and there and the code is somewhat basic, but I myself still unable to figure this one out & I need advice.

The thing is when I add the first two lines of [code provided on parse.com for saving objects](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-classes/iOS)

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
```

I get the following error for the second line:

> 'PFObject' does not have a member named 'subscript'

I'm on Xcode 6.3 beta 2.
All required libraries are linked with binary, `<Parse/Parse.h>` imported via BridgeHeader.

What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening due to the 1.6.4 version of the parse sdk which added Objective-C Nullability Annotations to the framework. In particular the file `Parse/PFObject.h` defines:

`- (PF_NULLABLE_S id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)key;`

which is causing the Swift compile error. Removing the `PF_NULLABLE_S` fixes the problem.

On the other hand it seems correct that an object for a keyed subscript might be `nil`, so I suspect this is a Swift bug...

Comment: What do you mean by removing `PF_NULLABLE_S`? Should I, say, comment `- (PF_NULLABLE_S id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)key;` line out?

Comment: I mean change it in `PFObject.h` to:

```-(id) objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)key;```

Comment: Thanks @kashif for figuring this out! I've added an answer that shows how you can solve this without changing the framework.

Comment: @ben-g cool thanks, I am using the `setObject(...)` myself... but yes I thank you too!

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be the changed method signature, as kashif suggested. Swift doesn't seem to be able to bridge to the Objective-C method because the signature no longer matches the subscript method names.

**Workaround 1**

You can work around this without modifying the framework by calling the subscript method directly, instead of using the `[]` operator:

**Instead of using the instruction below for getting the value of a particular key:**

```
let str = user["key-name"] as? Bool
```

**Please use the following instruction:**

```
let str = user.objectForKey("key-name") as? Bool
```

and

**Instead of using the instruction below for setting the value of a particular key:**

```
user["key-name"] = "Bla bla"
```

**Please use the following instruction:**

```
user.setObject("Bla bla", forKey: "key-name")
```

**Workaround 2**

Another solution is to add an extension on PFObject that implements the `subscript` member and calls `setValue:forKey:`:

```
extension PFObject {
  subscript(index: String) -> AnyObject? {
    get {
      return self.valueForKey(index)
    }
    set(newValue) {
      if let newValue: AnyObject = newValue {
        self.setValue(newValue, forKey: index)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this second workaround isn't entirely safe, since I'm not sure how Parse actually implements the subscript methods (maybe they do more than just calling `setValue:forKey` - it has worked in my simple test cases, so it seems like a valid workaround until this is fixed in Parse/Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Another workaround is to just go with the stable version of Xcode until 6.3 is mandatory. As a matter of fact, now I use 6.2 as my main IDE & 6.3 beta for adapting the more stable projects of mine to Swift 1.2.
As to `.setObject`, I've already been treating my code with it at the time I created this discussion, but I wanted to make sure `[ ]` operator no longer works in Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully run your exact code.

First, make sure you are indeed saving the object in the background, after you set the new value:

```
gameScore.save()
```

I would double check for misspellings in the class name and subclass; if they are incorrect, it will not work.

If that's not the problem, verify in Parse that the "score" subclass is set to be a number. If you accidentally set it to be a string, setting it as an integer will not work.

If these suggestions have not hit the solution, then I'm not sure what the problem is. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, in fact, they are the only two lines I wrote. So I'm not trying saving something, neither do I have an opportunity to misspell anything. And I get the same exact error with `gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"` &
`gameScore["cheatMode"] = false`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error with Parse 1.6.4 and 1.6.5 in the PFConstants.h header file with method parameters.

Xcode 6.3 beta 4 has a note in the "New in..." section regarding nullability operators.

Moving the nullability operator between the pointer operator and the variable name seems to comply/compile.

Changing:

```
PF_NULLABLE_S NSError *error
```

to:

```
NSError * PF_NULLABLE_S error 

  (i.e., NSError* __nullable error)
```

... resolved the compiler error.

This also worked for block parameters defined with id. So...

```
PF_NULLABLE_S id object
```

becomes:

```
id PF_NULLABLE_S object
```

In the above case, perhaps:

```
- (id PF_NULLABLE_S)objectForKeyedSubscript:(NSString *)key;
```

I.e., the nullability operator is after the pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while but I encountered a similar problem when I was starting my first Parse application with SDK version 1.9.1.

The Quickstart guide had the code below as an example as to how to save values:

```
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
testObject["foo"] = "bar"
testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  println("Object has been saved.")
}
```

But, the line `testObject["foo"] = "bar"` returned the error `'PFObject' does not have a member named 'subscript'`. I was able to work around the problem by changing the line to `testObject.setValue("bar", forKey: "foo")`. (As suggested by a tutorial video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kTw_cK3zY)