# How i make Column in Parse with Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, subscript, pfobject

I started learning programing just few weeks ago.
i am making some application with Swift and Parse

i have problem 
i install Parse SDK and Frameworks 
then i tried connect my app to Parse. (connecting was successful)
but
In test the SDK has some problems.

**testObject["foo"]** <- i can't write it
i don't know how solve it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bardd"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        println("Object has been saved.")
    }
```

**error messsage : PFObject does not have a memeber named 'subscript'**

if i delete **testObject["foo"] = "bardd"** ,all build well.
but in my Parse, there are nothing "foo" column..

Waiting reply!
Thanks you. ( Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Do you have column named "foo" created on your object on the Parse.com database ?

Comment: Thanks! i got solved problem!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953306/pfobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript) might help you. I experienced it once. It looks like it is a Framework-sided error.

Comment: Thanks! i got solved problem!