# upgrading swift code using ?? in cast

Tags: swift, parse-platform, casting, option-type

I have the following line of code from  `swift 1.1`.

Now that I've upgraded (currently only to `swift 1.2`) I'm getting a `runtime error` on the following line:

```
let myBool = parseObject["myBoolField"] as? Bool ?? false
```

Has something changed with newer versions of Swift that change the way you use  in casts?

Shouldn't this line **never fail** and always at least resolve to `myBool = false` ?

Comment: your code should work correctly. What is the message error?

Comment: I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors where there were none before. parseObject is non nil. Puzzling. What I can confirm is that myBoolField does not exist on the object. This is sometimes expected, hence the ?? false fallback.

Comment: You can try optional chaining to obtain your "myBoolField": `let myBool = parseObject["myBoolField"]?.boolValue ?? false`

Comment: The code above gives an error: operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is AnyObject

Comment: Could this be related to this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953306/pfobject-does-not-have-a-member-named-subscript